# Reduced real connective K theory of a point

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, vector-bundles, k-theory, topological-k-theory

I’ve just started reading about reduced real connective k-theory, denoted $\widetilde{ko}_*$. I’m familiar with real k-theory and complex k-theory, they’re reduced counterparts, and the definition of $ko_*$. However, I can’t seem to get straight the easiest case of $\widetilde{ko}_*(pt)$. For example, what is $\widetilde{ko}_i(pt)$ for low values of i? I imagine that we only have to do things up to $i=8$ by Bott periodicity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any reduced homology theory evaluates to $0$ on a point, in particular for reduced connective K-theory. More interesting is to ask what $\widetilde{ko}_*(S^0)$ is? By the definition of connective covers of spectra, if $* \geq 0$ then $\widetilde{ko}_*(S^0)=\pi_*(ko)=\pi_*(KO)=\widetilde{KO}_*(S^0)$; $0$ otherwise.

It is important to note this argument only works in the case of $\widetilde{ko}_*(S^0)$ and not for a general space.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As a follow up, could you please remind me of the first few values of $ko_*(pt)$?

Comment: @slowspider Like I said in the answer, the positive values coincide with $KO_*(pt)$ which are the homotopy groups of the spectrum $KO$ which are given by Bott periodicity.

Comment: Is it not true in general that $ko_*(X) = KO_*(X)$ for $*\geq 0$? I thought this was how $ko_*$ was defined.

Comment: @slowspider It's not true; there is not a reason for that to give a cohomology theory since it will not have a LES associated to a CW pair. Connective covers are built by taking fibers to the coconnective cover which is built by iteratively killing the higher homotopy groups of the spectrum.